# Can I edit a sharepoint list using Forms Services?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, infopath-forms-services

I don't know if I can edit a sharepoint list using Forms Services. Is it possible design Infopath Forms working with Sharepoint lists

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2010 (you did not mentioned the version) that is easy as cake, just hit Customize Form in the List Form and you're inside InfoPath with a editable version of the list.

In 2007 its more complicated, see [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc162745.aspx)